# bash script wp-cli search-replace 0 replacements, but command-line 3000+

Tags: wp-cli, command-line

I'm runnning this command;

```
sudo -u www-data wp search-replace www.siteurl.com www.newsiteurl.com --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
```

From command line: 3.456 replacements 
From bash-script: 0 replacements

the line in the bash script:

```
wp search-replace ${OLD_URL} ${NEW_URL} --recurse-objects --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users
```

I've tried trimming the variables, I've tried `${VAR}` and `$VAR`, and even `--path=/path/to/site`

The output table with details about replacements comes out on both bash and command-line versions.  0 replacements for the bash-script and 3.456 replacements from command line.

Comment: So when running the bash, you get an output and it just reads 0? Is there any other output? Have you tried adding `sudo` to the command in the script as well?

Comment: yep, dropped sudo -u www-data from the question, but it is there. and yes, I get the output, and it lists the same tables, but the results look like this;
    bash: Success: Made 0 replacements.
    command-line: Success: Made 3.456 replacements.

I've tried to put the whole thing in a variable and running eval $VAR;
result: the same, even when i do copy/paste of the command

    echo $VAR ->copied and then used on command line: 3.456 replacements;
    eval $VAR in the bash script -> 0 replacements

Comment: Puh ... I have no idea .. You could create a ticket on their [github](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli) (or ask directly in the #wp-cli channel on Slack), they can probably help you better than we

Comment: Actually this is a Bash question and should better be asked on Stack Overflow. But just for clarification, what happens when you put `echo ${OLD_URL}` and what when you put `echo "${OLD_URL}"` (with quotation marks) in your script?

Comment: Tried with and without quotes. same thing. Over to stack overflow. Will try to remember to post solution here when/if I find it :)

Comment: Problem seems to be solved :)
...
FIX_MY_OLD URL=$(echo ${OLD_URL} | iconv -f utf-8 -t us-ascii//TRANSLIT)
...
(There is no non-us-ascii characthers in the old url - but this dit it)